# How to assign the variable to a value in a conditional if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, null, conditional-statements

```
public String simpleConditional(int price)  {
        String answer = null ;
price = 20;
          if (price < 20)
              System.out.println("Buying new shirt");
answer = "Buying new shirt"
    
ConditionalStatementsTest > simpleConditionalTest(int, String) > com.ata.ConditionalStatements
Test.simpleConditionalTest(int, String)[3] FAILED                                             
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <Buying new shirt>         
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                  
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)          
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)             
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)             
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)                
        at com.ata.ConditionalStatementsTest.simpleConditionalTest(ConditionalStatementsTest.j
```

I am trying to equal the "answer" variable to the "Buying new shirt" value. And that is the Assertion error code I Receive with the code  stated above.
How would I solve resolve this error, it looks correct to me.( this is for a homework checker program)

Comment: Hey it seems that this is supposed to be tagged in Java but you've tagged it in Javascript

Comment: I'm terribly rusty in Java, but wouldn't it be similar to how you assigned `price`? in the if-statement, `answer ="Buying new shirt";`

Comment: for homework related questions, I'd recommend following this question when posting questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the code snippet that the return type is "String" so what you can do is the following if you want to return "Buying new shirt".

```
public String simpleConditional(int price) {
   String answer = null;
   price = 20;
   if(price < 20) {
     System.out.println("Buy new shirt");
     answer = "buy new shirt";
     return answer;       
   } else {
     return "Something else"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error code when i try and assign, it says org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <Buying new shirt>

Comment: What else you can do is to assign the answer = "Something else" and return the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
/**
 * Assumes the monetary value supplied is a floating point value.
 * 
 * @param price (double) Will return null if 0 or less is supplied.
 * 
 * @return (String)
 */
public static String simpleConditional(double price) {
    String answer = null;
    if (price > 0d && price < 20d) {
        System.out.println("Buy new shirt");
        answer = "buy new shirt";

    }
    else if (price >= 20d && price < 80d) {
        answer = "Hmmm...buying a decent shirt!";
    }
    else if (price >= 80d) {
        answer = "Wow...Big Spender, buying a really good shirt!";
    }
    return answer;
}
```

To use the method named `simpleConditional()` method within the class `main()` method you might do something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String anAnswer = simpleConditional(56.98);
    System.out.println(anAnswer);

    // The following will work to:
    System.out.println(simpleConditional(104));
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error code when i try and assign, it says  org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <Buying new shirt>

Comment: Then change the final `else` statement to: `else { answer = null; }`. Or...just remove the `else` block altogether since `answer` is already assigned null.